# Pending intent only allow me use an Activity, no Asynctask allowed

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-pendingintent

This is the part of code with the problem:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MyGcmListenerService.this, CalcularHorariosDisponiblesComplejo.class);
    intent.putExtra("idComplejo",idComplejoSeleccionado);
    intent.putExtra("idCancha",idCanchaSeleccionada);
    intent.putExtra("idUsuarioComplejo",idUsuarioComplejo);
    intent.putExtra("idPais",idPais);
    intent.putExtra("nombreComplejo", nombreComplejo);
    intent.putExtra("dia",day);
    intent.putExtra("mes",month);
    intent.putExtra("anio",year);

    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    MyGcmListenerService.this,
                    m,
                    intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );//creamos la notificacion
    NotificationCompat.Builder n  = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MyGcmListenerService.this)
            .setContentTitle(titulo)
            .setSound(uri)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
            .setLargeIcon(bm)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("El usuario " + nombreOrigen + " " + mensaje))
            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true);
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(m, n.build());
}
```

The pendingIntent works great, but I change the **CalcularHorariosDisponiblesComplejo.class** for a AsyncTask. Now I call the  sameclass like this:

```
        new CalcularHorariosComplejoAsyncTask(MyGcmListenerService.this, idComplejoSeleccionado, idCanchaSeleccionada, nombreComplejo, idUsuarioComplejo, idPais, String.valueOf(day),String.valueOf(month),String.valueOf(year)).execute();
```

The problem that now I can't use pending intent, so I try to replace something like this but is not working:

```
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
        PendingIntent.getActivity(
                MyGcmListenerService.this,
                m,
                new CalcularHorariosComplejoAsyncTask(MyGcmListenerService.this, idComplejoSeleccionado, idCanchaSeleccionada, nombreComplejo, idUsuarioComplejo, idPais, String.valueOf(day),String.valueOf(month),String.valueOf(year)).execute(),
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

**How can I call from PendingIntent to a Asynctask?**

Comment: Why don't you use an IntentService instead?

Comment: @MiguelBenitez I don't know, is it the best solution?, if you think so, give the the solution. Thanks

Comment: The solution is `PendingIntent.getService()`

Comment: Check the posted code.

Answer (score 0):

Declare it in the manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.app" >
        ...
        <service android:name="YOUR_APP_PACKAGE.CalcularHorariosComplejoService">
        </service>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Create the IntentService:

```
public class CalcularHorariosComplejoService extends IntentService {
    public CalcularHorariosComplejoService() {
        super("CalcularHorariosComplejoService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        //Calculo de horarios complejos

    }
}
```

And create the pending intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MyGcmListenerService.this, YOUR_APP_PACKAGE.CalcularHorariosComplejoService.class);
    intent.putExtra("idComplejo",idComplejoSeleccionado);
    intent.putExtra("idCancha",idCanchaSeleccionada);
    intent.putExtra("idUsuarioComplejo",idUsuarioComplejo);
    intent.putExtra("idPais",idPais);
    intent.putExtra("nombreComplejo", nombreComplejo);
    intent.putExtra("dia",day);
    intent.putExtra("mes",month);
    intent.putExtra("anio",year);

PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getService(MyGcmListenerService.this, 0, intent, 0);
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't have Activity! I have a Asynctask to call, no an activity.

Comment: The services and the notifications works perfect. The only problem is that on click the notification the service have to call a Asynctask, no an Activity before I've changed the code

Comment: It's not an activity, is an IntentService: IntentService (android.app.IntentService) is a simple type of service that can be used to handle asynchronous work off the main thread by way of Intent requests.

Comment: OK, but I have an error: "CalcularHorariosComplejoService is not an enclosing class"

Comment: My fault: PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getService(MyGcmListenerService.this, 0, intent, 0);

Comment: Now I have a problem: "Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?"  When the phone receive the notfication explote. Also don't let me touch the notification

Comment: Try intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);Also If you can provide me the logcat It could be useful

Comment: Anyway here It's a solution using Notifications without Activity and using intent service. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36433573/notification-action-without-starting-new-activity Hope works. Suerte

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117433/discussion-between-federick-jons-and-miguel-benitez).